# Can ISPs still throttle torrent traffic when using socks?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, bittorrent

I've seen guides telling users to use a VPN or SSH tunnel to avoid ISP throttling of bittorent traffic, but if you use a SOCKS(5) proxy wouldn't it be just as effective? My understanding of SOCKS is that it is encrypted, i.e. the ISP can not (easily) tell what kind of traffic is occurring between me and the proxy.

So using a SOCKS proxy **AND** VPN/SSH seems redundant?

But besides that, isn't the in-client encryption option good enough to avoid throttling? Assuming one is not worried about hiding their IP or bypassing local network filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOCKS does not use encryption, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/719/is-socks-secure) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123419/socks5-is-there-encryption-between-client-and-proxy-server). It’s much like using HTTP with a HTTP proxy.

Additionally, on Bittorrent encryption: It helps hide the contents of what you’re downloading. However, an ISP can still guess that the connections you’re making are P2P connections and throttle them accordingly. It’s a behavioral analysis of sorts, it takes into account ports and address ranges as well as packet sizes.